# How to open a PDF in application and save it back to SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, app, pdf

Has anyone figured out how to open a PDF in the application and save it back in SharePoint Online with out downloading and then uploading it back? The issue is that we have fillable PDFs that need to be updated on a regular basis

Here are some similar articles:
https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/12336546-open-adobe-pdf-in-client-application
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_win10-mso_o365b/i-need-to-open-and-edit-pdf-files-from-sharepoint/7ecbdc54-4ece-4697-9425-756e7099249a

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have installed the client application which can open PDF files (such as Adobe) in the current machine. Make sure the proper browser plug-in is disabled/enabled. For the Adobe, check whether the Adobe Pdf Reader add-on is disabled or the Adobe Acrobat sharepoint OpenDocuments Component add-on is enabled in Internet Explorer.

Currently, Acrobat and Acrobat Reader let you open and save files to online file management services, such as Dropbox, Microsoft SharePoint, OneDrive, and Box. Refer to https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/online-accounts.html

Upgrade to the latest version, see if it works.

A thread from Adobe forum with similar question:

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1997669

Comment: So this is where it gets a little confusing. We don't have Adobe Reader or other installed on our machines, our Default application is Nitro PDF.

Comment: I also do not see any browser plugins or options that I can disable, I will try submitting a ticket with their support and see if they have any recommendations.

Comment: Ryan - this is one of the biggest problems with SharePoint (Online) - the lack of integration with PDF editors. My clients want to be able to edit directly from SharePoint in the same way as they do with Office desktop apps. I've been seeking a solution for years but it's a bit like the holy grail! Please post back if you get it sorted. My client uses Nitro Pro as well. They do have a DMS plugin but I've yet to try it